# Error en fetch invalid json response

Tags: javascript, express, fetch

Hice un `fetch` a una `API` externa a mi proyecto y me el error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: FetchError: invalid json response body at url reason: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0

la url es válida y acepta los encabezados, manda la respuesta, pero aparece el error, ahora copiaré el link de respuesta que da la `API`:

```
"/**/res({"findItemsByKeywordsResponse":[{"ack":["Success"],"version":["1.13.0"],"timestamp":["2019-09-02T13:39:19.579Z"],"searchResult":[{"@count":"20","item":[{"itemId":["153513116433"],"title":["GANO CAFE 3 IN 1 COFFEE WITH GANODERMA LUCIDUM -New and Sealed\/ FREE US SHIPPING"],"globalId":["EBAY-US"],"primaryCategory":[{"categoryId":["185039"],"categoryName":["Other Coffee"]}],"galleryURL":["https:\/\/thumbs2.ebaystatic.com\/m\/mCKnnhZXZZK3YIUuXufHM3w\/140.jpg"],"viewItemURL":["https:\/\/www.ebay.com\/itm\/GANO-CAFE-3-1-COFFEE-GANODERMA-LUCIDUM-New-and-Sealed-FREE-US-SHIPPING-\/153513116433"],"paymentMethod":["PayPal"],"autoPay":["false"],"postalCode":["78723"],"location":["Austin,TX,USA"],"country":["US"],"shippingInfo":[{"shippingServiceCost":[{"@currencyId":"USD","__value__":"0.0"}],"shippingType":["Free"],"shipToLocations":["Worldwide"],"expeditedShipping":["false"],"oneDayShippingAvailable":["false"],"handlingTime":["2"]}],"sellingStatus":[{"currentPrice":[{"@currencyId":"USD","__value__":"23.99"}],"convertedCurrentPrice":[{"@currencyId":"USD","__value__":"23.99"}],"sellingState":["Active"],"timeLeft":["P1DT16H18M1S"]}],"listingInfo":[{"bestOfferEnabled":["false"],"buyItNowAvailable":["false"],"startTime":["2019-06-04T05:57:20.000Z"],"endTime":["2019-09-04T05:57:20.000Z"],"listingType":["FixedPrice"],"gift":["false"],"watchCount":["10"]}],"returnsAccepted":["true"],"condition":[{"conditionId":["1000"],"conditionDisplayName":["New"]}],"isMultiVariationListing":["false"],"topRatedListing":["false"]},{"itemId":["273957218963"],"
```

es mucho mas largo el archivo, pero es para que se hagan una idea de que la respuesta es válida y no es problema de encabezados ni de url.
Este es el código que ocupo:

```
app.get ('/', async function  (req, respues, next) {
  function respu() { 
    return fetch(url)
  }
  const respuesta = async () => { 
   const res= await respu() 
   const respuesta = await res.json()

   console.log (respuesta)
 }
 respuesta () 
 respues.end 
}) 

app.use(cors());
```

Uso `JS`, y el `server` es `express`

Comment: La respuesta parece JSONP, no JSON, deberías estudiar la documentación del API al que estás accediendo para ver por qué te da esa respuesta

Comment: estás usando el next en la implementación, como si fuera middleware, si esa era tu intención debes usar next() en algún punto de tu código, si no debes eliminarlo.